# unable to update field with flow

Tags: visual-workflow, field-update

please find the edited version :

-basically what I want to see is how many tasks a user creates and save the final number in a "Targets" object.(simulation of a roll-up summary field)

- type of flow : record triggered flow.

1st step: user creates a task

2nd step: the flow gathers all the tasks under this user's ownership:

[image]

3rd step : assignment: the flow sums up the number of collected records

[image]

4th step: find the record that needs to be updated in the given object and update the designated field with the number resulted from the assignment.  :

[image]

"Result:
All records that meet the filter criteria are ready to be updated when the next screen, pause, or local action is executed or when the interview finishes."

This is the final line in the flow debug, after i run my flow.

Simple record-triggered flow with : get records- assignment - update record (in a different object) steps.
The flow is doing the following: new task is created and status changed to completed, counts all the completed tasks of the owner and updates a record in a different object with the result of the counting. Basically it simulates a roll-up summary field.

Would you have any idea why i am not getting the field update?
Thank you

What could be the possible reason for the message above?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/367506/edit) your question to include some screenshots of your Flow, and/or a better-and-easier-to-follow description of each Flow element. It is hard to follow and understand what your Flow is doing. The built-in formatting tools in the Stack Exchange question/answer editor can help with that - bulleted lists, numbered lists, tables, code block, etc. | And please include what type of Flow it is.

Comment: Also - if you are running the Flow debug in rollback mode, you will not see any actual field update outside of the Flow debugger.

Comment: Hello Moonpie, thank you for the welcoming. i have made the requested editing. hopefully it is a bit more transparent this way. thank you

Comment: Thank you for updating - that helps. Please elaborate on what you mean when you say that you are "not getting the field update" - where are you looking?

Comment: so the field " target up to date " is located on a custom object which is supposed to measure targets. i am expecting to see a different number in that field every time i create a new task, however there is no update happening there.  see a printscreen in edit

Answer (score 1):

In your *Update Records* Flow element, you are trying to update records where

```
BDR_Targets__c.Id = Task.OwnerId
```

I think it is safe to say that those will never match up, since according to Salesforce documentation *< https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_task.htm >* the Owner of a Task record is either a User or a Group.

Since BDR Target records are not Users or Groups, that means there are no *"records that meet the filter criteria"*.

You need to use whatever your connection is between `Task` and `BDR_Targets__c`.

**Example 1**: Let's say you have a field on the BDR Target object called *Associated Task* which holds the `Id` value of a Task record. *(* Associated Task *does not necessarily have to be a lookup - it could just hold the Id with no "direct" connection to the Task.)*

In this case, your *Update Records* Flow element condition would look more like

```
BDR_Targets__c.Associated_Task__c = Task.Id
```

**Example 2**: Let's say the Owner of a Task is also the Owner of BDR Target records and that is how they are connected.

In this case, your *Update Records* Flow element condition would look more like

```
BDR_Targets__c.OwnerId = Task.Owner.Id
```

Comment: thank you for your time. will figure it out somehow. so you are saying that in this case  the lookup relation has to be used somehow

Comment: As I was writing this response, I realized that I might have spoken too soon. I am unfamiliar with Tasks, so I assumed that the Owner was a User (or possibly a Group). In looking at the Salesforce documentation just now, I confirmed that is the case: either a User or a Group. So unless a `BDR_Targets__c` record *is* a User or a Group, then it cannot be the Owner of a `Task` record.

Comment: yes i confirm that. that was my logic behind that since both are users, the matching should happen on that basis.